# Building a single package containing multi-env setup with Maven

Tags: java, resources, maven, environment

we are asked to build package that contains configurations for ALL environments, the resulting package should like:
/bin
/lib
/config/prd/instance1
/config/prd/instance2
/config/uat/instance1

All config files are filtered and we can apply filters with resources plugin to build for 1 environment by specifying different profiles.

How can we extend the package to include other environments?

Answer (score 0):

First, just FYI: package is part of the build lifecycle. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). You can't really extend IT per se, however, you can add in additional plugins that run during that cycle.

Take a look at the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). I believe that with it you should be able to provide a custom assembly descriptor to suit your needs.